# Using two joins on one table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Since adding the middle part of the query (INNER JOIN) the query is now failing. I think this is probably because I have two types on joins on one table (charts_extended) - I cannot see another way to grab the required data from the dj_love table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT releases . * 
FROM releases
INNER JOIN artist_love ON releases.all_artists LIKE CONCAT( '%', artist_love.artist, '%' ) 
AND artist_love.user = 'Quickinho'
INNER JOIN label_love ON releases.label_no_country = label_love.label
AND label_love.user = 'Quickinho'

INNER JOIN charts_extended ON charts_extended.release_id = releases.id
WHERE charts_extended.artist
IN (

    SELECT dj
    FROM dj_love
    WHERE user =  'Quickinho'
    )

LEFT JOIN charts_extended ON charts_extended.release_id = releases.id
AND charts_extended.artist = 'Quickinho'
WHERE charts_extended.release_id IS NULL 

ORDER BY releases.date DESC
```

Comment: How about another JOIN - no subquery needed

Comment: Where you recommend adding the JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT releases . * 
FROM releases
INNER JOIN artist_love
    ON releases.all_artists LIKE CONCAT( '%', artist_love.artist, '%' ) AND artist_love.user = 'Quickinho'
INNER JOIN label_love
    ON releases.label_no_country = label_love.label AND label_love.user = 'Quickinho'
INNER JOIN charts_extended as a
    ON a.release_id = releases.id
LEFT JOIN charts_extended as b
    ON b.release_id = releases.id
        AND b.artist IN (SELECT dj FROM dj_love WHERE user =  'Quickinho')
        AND b.artist = 'Quickinho'
WHERE
    b.release_id IS NULL 

ORDER BY releases.date DESC
```

Comment: This is working (once I assigned an alias to the INNER JOIN charts_extended) but it seems to be ignoring the 'WHERE
    charts_extended.release_id IS NULL ' part of the LEFT JOIN. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: WHERE is not part of left join, it is part of filtering, and if you select this column you will see only NULL values in it, I've noticed problem with aliasing - check updated query